# How to animate an object to revolve around a fixed point in blender?

Tags: animation

I want to animate the revolution of earth around the sun in blender. I know that keyframes can be used to make an object revolve on its own axis. But how do I make an object revolve around an external fixed axis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As example I have a cube that revolves around an empty

- Add empty and add cube
  [image: List item]
- Select the cube and then select the empty and press <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>p</kbd> and select *Object*, the cube is parented to the empty
  [image]
- Select empty and press <kbd>I</kbd> and select rotation, so the empty has a *rotation keyframe*
  [image]
- the timeline you can use to pick another frame and enter 360 in highlight and press <kbd>I</kbd> to insert a keyframe:
  [image]